# Safari on Mac won't load some images in justified gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, macos, safari

I have a site which uses justified-gallery (http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/). We've had reports from some Mac users that in Safari, some of the photos won't load. I've managed to replicate the issue as well:

[image]

When using the console, it shows:

> Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost

Upon viewing the error'd image in a new tab, they load fine. These images aren't loaded in ajax or anything, they use a little bit of javascript to work out the best size photo and then load the image using JavaScript.

Here is a link to the page:

https://www.ephotozine.com/gallery

I haven't found anything that yet that points to a particular problem.

Comment: Does this happen on jsfiddle too?

Comment: @Tushar It appears the problem is only in Safari on Yosemite. It doesn't exist on El Capitan. Some reading leads me to believe its to do with HTTP Compression for some reason.